# Chrony on RHEL7.2 can sync to windows ntp server, But Chrony on RHEL7.4 can't sync it

Tags: redhat, ntp

according to redhat link:

```
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3425701
```

we can see that - Chrony on RHEL7.2 can sync to windows ntp server, But Chrony on RHEL7.4 can't sync it.

in my case we have redhat 7.5

how to know if the problem with chrony is the same also on redhat 7.5 or maybe already solved ?

Comment: Your question links to subscriber-only content, and doesn't contain enough information to diagnose your problem.  If you'd like help, please provide the exact configurations of your RHEL & Windows time sync services, and exact package version numbers.

Comment: I only refer to redhat article case , since redhat not supply  more info I cant understand if this case is only to redhat 7.4 or maybe also to redhat 7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to register for free a developer subscription to gain access to these RedHat articles.

Saying the above there are two proposed solutions there:

- Use NTP server on RHEL instead of Windows.
- Add maxdistance parameter to greater than 3 in the /etc/chrony.conf

More details also in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1525833